# What does macro mean?

Tags: language-agnostic, macros, definition

I have somewhat experience with what people call excel "macros". The vba code that controls the activeX components, right?

But I still do not know the true meaning of the term macro :). What kind of code is called macro? Is it something like vba or js implemented into a program? Like vba to excel or vba to autocad or js to flex?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has the answer, under [Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)).

Definition:

> The term originated with **macro-assemblers**, where the idea is to make available to the programmer a sequence of computing instructions as a single program statement, making the programming task less tedious and less error-prone.

Usage:

> Keyboard and mouse macros that are created using an application's built-in macro features are sometimes called application macros. They are created by carrying out the sequence once and letting the application record the actions. An underlying macro programming language, most commonly a Scripting language, with direct access to the features of the application may also exist.

There's lots more, if you follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to MS Office products (Excel, Access, Word, PowerPoint etc), "macro" is VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) code.
NOTE: In Access databases macro can also mean another type of automation besides VBA code.

Since you mentioned Excel...I will talk about Excel.

If you suspect (or know) there is an Excel file with macro, try hitting the Alt + F11 key when you have the Excel file open.
You should see a VBA screen open.
This is where you might be able to see the VBA code (ie, if it is not locked behind a password by the programmer who wrote the VBA code).

Macro (VBA code) is used to automated certain tasks.
So in Excel VBA programmer could put a button on a sheet and when you click the button some activities might take place in the Excel file - activities like calculations, copying, pasting, deleting etc..

Read up a little on "recording a macro in Excel".